# Perl Regex - Get offset as line number instead of character position in case of a MATCH

Tags: regex, perl, offset

I am reading a complete file in a string and then doing a regex match as below:

```
if($str =~ m/$regex/gc) {
     $offset = $+[0];
}
```

Using this code, I can capture the position where the last successful match ends.

Now this will give the position as character number.

**Is there any way that I can get offset as line number?**

What I am doing for now is that I am counting the number of newline characters from beginning of `$str` upto end `$offset`.

I want to know is there a direct way to capture line number for a regex match.

Comment: nope, its not possible. by definition regex operates on string, which might include newline(s). so what you have is good. hope you had exercised caution on reading whole file into memory

Comment: I guess your way (counting the number of \n) is the only way. Regex works with strings as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to what one might imagine, [Nahuel's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11411326/133939) of using [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) is actually doable in this case.

This is because one can read from strings just like files using Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = <<EOS;
spam
spam
spam
match
spam
match
EOS

open my $handle, '<', \$str or die $!;

while ( <$handle> ) {

    print $., "\n" if /match/;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
4
6
```

Comment: Can't help chuckling over "open my handle or die!".

Answer (score 1):

see perldoc perlvar, special variable `$.`

EDIT: after comment, sorry I read too fast

another solution, if there is many matches, could be to create an array which contains offset of new lines: $a[0]-> offset of line 2, etc. then to approximate the line number and finally increase or decrease to find the line.
May have a problem if the last line does not contain a newline character.

```
# create an array with offset of new lines
@a=(0,0);push@a,$-[0]while$str=~/\n/gc;

if($str =~ m/$regex/gc) {
  $offset = $+[0]; 
  # get an approximation of line
  $l=int$offset*@a/$a[-1];
  # increment or decrement
  $l++while$a[$l+1]<$offset;
  $l--while$a[$l]>$offset;
}
```

EDIT:
not tested,
changes initialize @a=(0,0) to avoid +2 at the end and safe if match on first line
$l++while$a[$l+1]$offset
and *@a added

Comment: $. will not help since I am reading the whole file in a string

Comment: @Saumitra : It will help. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11411752/133939)